# Connect to HDFS with keytab of a serviceID with Python3.6

Tags: python-3.x, kerberos, keytab, python-hdfs

I am trying the below piece of code to connect to hdfs and do some file related operation. Please note I am trying to connect a Cloudera HDFS instance from a Centos7 environment with python3.6 installed into it.

```
import io 
from csv import reader
from krbcontext import krbcontext
from hdfs.ext.kerberos import KerberosClient


    
def getKerberosClient(host, port, root):
    
    url = 'http://{host}:{port}/'.format(host=host, port=port)
    client = KerberosClient(url, root=root)
    return client

def main():
    try:
        krb = krbcontext(using_keytab=True,principal='svcid213@AMER.SOMEORG.COM',keytab_file="/nfs-hdfs/kerberos/svcid213_AMER.SOMEORG.COM.keytab")
        print(F'kerberos authentication successful {krb}')
        kerberos_client = getKerberosClient('deltanileuat01.amer.someorg.com', 14000, "/")
        print(F'kerberos_client {kerberos_client}')
        result = kerberos_client.status("/")
        print(F"Output ============\n {result} \n =========================")
    except Exception as e:
        print(F"Detailed error is : {e} ")
   
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am running it from an centos-7 environment with python3.6 installed [ PS: *no hdfs client installed* ].
Before I executed the code I have have done the pip install as below

```
pip3.6 install kerberos
pip3.6 install requests-kerberos
pip3.6 install hdfs
```

On executing I am getting as below

```
kerberos authentication successful <krbcontext.context.krbContext object at 0x7f1f7269c208>
kerberos_client <KerberosClient(url='http://deltanileuat01.amer.someorg.com:14000/')>
Detailed error is : Authentication failure. Check your credentials.
```

I am probably missing on some configuration here.
This keytab is working all good with JAVA application to connect to the hdfs. With python it is showing up this error.
Please advise that to execute the above code if
a) The HDFS client needs to be configured at the execution environment
OR
b) `kinit` is something that needs to be done. Please note that we are using a service id to connect to the hdfs with the keytab file.

Comment: Please make your comment into an answer and self-mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The above issue resolved by doing a kinit with the Service-ID and the keytab file. The code then executes all fine

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your solution?